# Ray: Object creation will fail if spilling is required

Tags: ray

With only initializing Ray, I get continuous warnings that I have no disk space:

```
# start Ray
import ray
import psutil
# Start Ray
num_cpus = psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)
if not ray.is_initialized():
    context = ray.init(num_cpus=num_cpus)
```

```
(raylet) file_system_monitor.cc:111: 
/tmp/ray/session_2023-06-29_11-21-28_818264_5598 is over 95% full, 
available space: 1392345088; capacity: 269427478528. 
Object creation will fail if spilling is required
```

I tried specifying a separate path as mentioned in the docs ([https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/objects/object-spilling.html#:~:text=Ray%20uses%20object%20spilling%20by,temp_folder%20is%20%2Ftmp%20by%20default.](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/objects/object-spilling.html#:%7E:text=Ray%20uses%20object%20spilling%20by,temp_folder%20is%20%2Ftmp%20by%20default.)), to no avail:

```
ray.init(
    num_cpus=num_cpus=num_cpus,
    _system_config={
        "object_spilling_config": json.dumps(
            {"type": "filesystem", "params": {"directory_path": "/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/tmpxd"}},
        )
    },
)
```